# Can't seem to pass JS argument (variable) to Google Map API v3 function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, variables, google-maps-api-3

I'm attempting to move a large block of Google Maps API script off of the page and into an included .js file.

But! In order to do that I've got to tweak the function to accept passed variables.

Here's the start of the script normally...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function loadGmap() {
  var map1options = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-12.043333,-77.028333),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    zoom: 4,
    minZoom: 2,
    streetViewControl: false
  };
```

and here's me try to pass the first variable (and failing)...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function loadGmaps() {
  loadGmap('-12.043333,-77.028333');
}

function loadGmap(coordinates) {
  var map1options = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    zoom: 4,
    minZoom: 2,
    streetViewControl: false
  };
```

Ideas? Maybe this shouldn't be a string... or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-12.043333,-77.028333),
```

There you pass two arguments to `LatLng`.  In your new function, you still need to pass two arguments to `LatLng`.  The easiest way to do this is to accept two arguments to your function:

```
function loadGmaps() {
    loadGmap(-12.043333,-77.028333);
}

function loadGmap(lat, lng) {
    var map1options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
        zoom: 4,
        minZoom: 2,
        streetViewControl: false
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the same arguments... That method accepts 2 arguments: latitude and longitude, not a single string argument.

```
function loadGmaps() {
    loadGmap(-12.043333, -77.028333);
}

function loadGmap(lat, long) {
    var map1options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to this line:

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(
  parseFloat(coordinates.split(",")[0]), 
  parseFloat(coordinates.split(",")[1])
),
```

Comment: Also a neat take on things, but certainly simpler to not pass a string. Thank you

Comment: Of course, but this is the copy & paste & wonder later proposal. Just in case you need to move your stuff through the door.

Answer (score 0):

As of recent you need to CAST the LatLng variables as follows:

buildinglatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Number(maplatitude), Number(maplongitude));